# How to get, delete or publish wordpress 4.9 post from powershell using Rest API?

Tags: json, wordpress, powershell, http-post

I have found this [powershell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-delete-or-6a15fe7d/view/Discussions#content) on technet. Description says: Step 1 - install "JSON Basic Authentication" and "WP REST API" by WP REST API Team.
While WP REST API Team says "[The REST API is included in WordPress 4.7](http://v2.wp-api.org)" so plugin no longer required.

But now **wp-restApi.ps1** script no longer working with WP 4.9. Returning next error "**Invoke-WebRequest** : The remote server returned an error: **(401) Unauthorized**."

How to post to WP 4.7 and newer with powershell ***Invoke-WebRequest -method post*** ?

```
#post title and content 
$params = @{ 
    title = "test Rest API post" 
    content = "test Rest API post content" 
    status = 'publish' 
} 
#change username and password before use 
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("user:pass@23"))) 
$header = @{ 
Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) 
} 
$params1=$params|ConvertTo-Json 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri http://khaoodara.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts -ContentType "application/json" -Body $params1  -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: The account you're trying to make changes with doesn't have authorization to do what you're trying, hence the HTTP401..

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  the account have moderator level privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to install **WP-API/Basic-Auth** Wordpress [plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) and script start to work.